# Asking permission for Application update

Tags: android, google-play, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I am going to update an application to Android 6.0. For users who already have the application installed when an update is made, are all the permissions still active or is the user going to be asked for permissions that are in the dangerous category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will still ask them to allow those permissions if they are in the dangerous category, regardless if they are specified in the manifest.  (i.e Writing to SD, Using the camera) See [Permission Groups](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups)

If you have users who are on Android 6.0 Marshmallow and your application only specifies permissions in the manifest and not at run time then those actions will fail. For example, if you have code that writes to the external storage, it will fail and give a `Permission Denied` error.

Comment: Do I have to ask for all the permissons at the lunch or can I ask them as the application needs them?

Comment: Ask for them as you need them, per activity. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#make-the-request